# Adobe reader - Javascript error when closing/saving a digitally signed pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, adobe-javascript

I am trying to save a digitally signed pdf. But when I close the document after clicking on save, I get this error in the javascript console.

**NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method.
Doc.URL:2:XFA:FormSchV_Dtls[0]:docClose**

Its like the macros are not getting saved. I have to upload this file on the MCA server as I have to file a return, but the server is rejecting it. PLease help me out !!

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

Does the document by chance have a willClose script?

From the error message, it seems that the document is not really a PDF, but an XFA file.

With "regular" PDFs, applying a digital signature (a real one), implies saving the document. You might check whether this happens. Then you will no longer need to save it specifically, but can close it immediately.